# Historical background of wave function collapse

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, history, wavefunction-collapse, born-rule

I wonder what were the main experiments that led people to develop the concept of wave function collapse? (I think I am correct in including the Born Rule within the general umbrella of the collapse paradigm.) Are there any instances where cases once thought to be examples of collapse have since been explained as the normal time-evolution of the wave function?

EDIT: I'm going to have to make an objection to Ron Maimon's very excellent answer about particle tracks as evidence of collapse. I've been waiting for someone to suggest what I personally have always considered the prototype of the wave function collapse, namely the appearance of flecks of silver on a photographic plate when exposed to the light of a distant star. This has the essential elements of collapse in a way that ordinary photographic exposures do not. The mere appearance of dots on a photographic plate does not signal the collapse of anything: it is readily explainable as a consequence of the rate of silver-bromide reduction being proportional to light intensity. It is only when the intensity becomes so very low that the time taken to accumulate enough energy for a single conversion becomes unreasonable that we must consider the explanation of wave function collapse.

The tracks in the cloud chamber do not demonstrate this phenomenon since the energy needed for the creation of the tracks is already available in the supersaturated gas. It is not necessary for the incoming particle to supply energy for the creation of the track, so there is no need to collapse its wave function. The straightness of the tracks is explained by Mott as an ordinary consequence of time-evolution of the wave function. There is no experimental proof that a single "particle" cannot be responsible for multiple tracks in the cloud chamber, because the tracks are not tagged according to which particle created them.

Comment: No, the Born rule produces probabilities, which are then open to any number of interpretations. Statistical, Many Worlds, you name it. The Born rule *certainly* does not put you into a collapse interpretation. If you go the history of Physics route, there are quite different rules of engagement than if you do Physics. The Questions you ask here are too leading for the History of Physics paradigm, at least as I see it.

Comment: @Peter Morgan It's not that important to me which way you go with it, whether you collapse the wave function or you go with Many Worlds: the experiments we are trying to explain are still the same experiments. I could have just as well asked "what were the phenomena that led people to come up with Many Worlds, or the Born rule...they're still the same phenomena aren't they?

Comment: @Marty, They may be the same phenomena, but the models, descriptions, and explanations that we use can be very different. There was a strongly empiricist flavor to Physics in the early days of QM, which loosely can be characterized as "don't ask for explanations", just look for effective models and descriptions of experiments, and I think you're missing an appreciation of that in your Question. There has been something of a revival of the demand for explanation, since the 1950s, perhaps, but there is no well accepted account of precisely how one should balance that with empiricism. V.Delicate!

Comment: The observation of the quantum Zeno effect makes wave function collapse difficult to deny.

Comment: In regard to your last question: *every* instance of what used to be thought as wavefunction collapse has since been explained as normal time-evolution. That is because wavefunction collapse itself is just approximate description of an actual real process of decoherence (in the limit of instantenous and complete decoherence). But the first part of the question about historical experiments is still interesting.

Comment: @Marek I guess I should ask you to explain to Jerry how decoherence explains the quantum Zeno effect. Seriously, this is the kind of answer that frustrates me because it deals only in generalities, where I have asked for specific examples. If decoherence explains everything, then how does the energy of light from a distant star get concentrated enought to reduce an atom of metallic silver on a photographic plate?

Comment: @Jerry Your example is interesting but it is surely not one of the cases which led people to come up with the idea of wave function collapse in the first place.

Comment: @Marty: decoherence is by now a standard textbook stuff and every experiment (and in particular yours) can be explained by it. Do you expect me to convey to you a one semester course on decoherence in this comment thread? If you want that question of yours get answered, at the very least, ask it as a separate one ;) It's not that easy, especially when you seem *not* to believe that it is the case decoherence works (which means you are probably not familiar with it at all).

Comment: @Marty: as to Jerry's comment. Note that nobody is saying that collapse is wrong in any sense. It is just an approximation to a more precise description. So if that description works for some problem, there's no need to find a more elementary one. In the same spirit, you wouldn't expect me to explain to you motion of a thrown stone by quantum mechanics when standard Newtonian one is perfectly good for that...

Comment: @Marty: Then I reading early papers on QM (or even hear some colleagues nowaday) I feel, that at that time collapse was simply “an obvious thing” and so any experiment demonstrated quantum behavior could be considered as proof of collapse. Someone used comparison with idea, that “it is obvious, that Sun moves around Earth, because we see that every day.”

Comment: @Alex Before there was a wavefunction, there was the idea of the "Quantum Leap" which was a kind of precursor to the idea of wave function collapse. It applied to all kinds of things like the transition of an electron between energy levels in the hydrogen atom of the splitting of a beam of silver atoms into two paths in the Stern Gerlach experiment. These are not exactly "wave function collapse because there was no wave function back then. When Schroedinger invented the wave function these phenomena were instantly explainable as normal time evolution.

Comment: @Marty: Idea of quantum jumps is still alive together with idea of Bohm and some other ideas, but you asked about wave function.

Comment: @Marty: You miss the point that the "supersaturated gas" is not supplying ionization energy, the electron is. I was going to upvote your question, but you keep repeating nonsense about the lack of collapse in EM waves with few photons. The electron track is more obvious, because the electron is not absorbed, but keeps ionizing atoms in its path. Repeat, there is no way the gas can ionize its atoms spontaneously. The supersaturation just makes the ions visible by droplet condensation.

Comment: Yes, I did miss that point. I read the Mott paper a couple of years ago and I don't remember the role of ionization in the process. I don't believe Mott dealt in any way with the mechanism of track formation. What exactly is the importance of ionization? Isn't the cloud chamber in a metastable state to begin with, and won't the clouds eventually just form on their own without any disturbance?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: there is a review paper written only five years ago

Experimental motivation and empirical consistency in minimal no-collapse quantum mechanics, Maximilian Schlosshauer, Ann. Phys. 321, 112-149 (2006)

Here is a cite from outlook: “We have analyzed three important experimental domains —namely, SQUIDs, molecular diffraction, and Bose-Einstein condensation [...] These experiments have provided powerful examples for the validity of unitary Schroedinger dynamics and the superposition principle on increasingly large length scales.”

Comment: I'm sorry to say I don't find this answer helpful.

Comment: @Marty Green: Why?

Comment: I don't mean to be difficult, but since you ask: 1. I don't have access to Annalen; 2. I asked for specific examples of wave function collapse and I can't see any in your answer; 3. your examples don't seem to fit the category of cases that led people to develop the concept; 4. I don't really understand the examples referred to in the paper. On the positive side, you do seem to be arguing in favor of time evolution vs collapse, but it's not helpful because you don't explain a specific mechanism in any case.

Comment: @Marty: Free online version of the paper is here http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0506199 but afraid it won't make you happy. My main reason for the cite was to show that there is quite solid view that there are no any experimental evidence of collapse at all. Yet I am not demanding that in future some experiments may not to prove collapse.

Comment: @Alex Thanks Alex for dealing with objections 1 and 4. Interesting paper. But re objection 2: these are not examples of wave function collapse: they are examples where collapse doesn't occur. They are nice examples but they're not what I asked for. I'm going to put up a new question where I ask for a specific mechanism to explain the flecks of silver on a photographic plate. I hope you'll check it out.

Comment: @Marty: I think it is an answer - you asked about examples and there is written that such examples do not exist. In the paper I cited mechanisms like flecks are also explained. It is all about Sun moving around Earth. I am not voting for such kind of explanations, I just may say, it may not be disproved using current state.

Comment: @Alex Could you give me a page number where the flecks are explained? I can't find it. As for examples not existing: I asked for examples of experiments that led people to formulate certain ideas. You may argue that the examples are discredited but that doesn't mean they don't exist. The paper you cite certainly does not make such a claim.

Comment: @Marty: I wrote "mechanisms like flecks" (i.e. similar with flecks, sorry my poor English). It is written there "(iii) no positive experimental evidence exists for physical state-vector collapse;"

Comment: @Alex If your English were not better than my Russian we wouldn't be having this discussion in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

My distinct impression is that wave function collapse is due to Dirac, and that it was not very directly based on experiment.  I am addressing the question historically, as it was asked.  Weyl's book although an attempt to axiomatise QM, and written based on a seminar where he, I think, had the help of Debye and Schrodinger, does not have this concept nor pose it as an axiom.  Dirac's book, published a little later but based on lectures he had been giving around the world for more than a year, did.

Dirac explains in his book very clearly that on which he is basing his assertion, the wave collapse, and it isn't experiment, it is « The Principle of Physical Continuity.»  Since in polarisation experiments the observed fact is that only an entire photon is observed on the other side of the polariser, and never part of one, he *deduces* logically, using the principle of continuity, that the photon must be in the eigenstate corresponding to that eigenvalue.  My copy of his book is not to hand so I can't give an exact quote...or can I?

Comment: This is correct as far as Dirac goes, but the "principle of physical continuity" is just the statement that if you measure the spin, and measure again, you don't get a different answer. but I pretty sure that Heisenberg knew collapse earlier, along with Bohr and Born. When Heisenberg studied the problem of particle tracks, ionizing atoms one after another, he showed that the multi-dimensional

Answer (score 1):

I believe the notion of collapse of the wavefunction is most explicitly derived from the resolution of the 1929 Mott paradox: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mott_problem .

The Mott problem considers an electron in a spherically symmetric wave, washing over a bunch of atoms. This electron will ionize the atoms, but not in a spherically symmetric way! We know that we will see the electron's trajectory through the atoms by looking at the ionization trail, as in a bubble chamber picture.

The Mott Heisenberg analysis showed that a spherical S-wave for a high energy electron travelling through a bunch of atoms indeed does lead the atoms to ionize along certain tracks, but only if you consider the full wavefunction of the atoms and the electron. The entanglement of the two means that once one atom is ionized, the next atom will be ionized on this Everett branch in the same general direction, although with some statistical spread.

The Mott/Heisenberg analysis makes it clear that the ionization "collapses" the wavefunction of the electron. This is then turned into a general principle, whereby any interaction which gives classical information which can be irreversibly amplified up for us to see leads to collapse of the wavefunction.

The many-worlds interpretation comes later, but the spark of the mathematical ideas (although not the philosophical leaps, nor the information theory aspects analyzed by Everett under Wheeler) are mainly contained in the Mott Heisenberg analysis.

But collapse was also evident from the formulation of the atom-radiation field theory in the late 1920s, where photons are real things, and energy conservation is maintained nonetheless. I don't know the exact history, and it might be correct to attribute this to Bohr, Heisenberg, Born, Dirac, or maybe even Pauli.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent response, Ron. The comment field is too short for me to respond to it so I have placed my response as an edit to my question.

Comment: @ron I’ve read the 1929 paper, think it’s still the best primer on how to think about QM.  Question I still have though is how this aligns with Renninger’s negative result measurements? How does the lack of interaction modify the wavefunction in an irreversible way?